# Renaming deep learning layers causes bad results

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I created two CNN models using Keras. The models give good accuracy results. To concatenate these models together to create a multi input model, I have to change the names of the layers **to be unique**. So, I changed the layers names in the second model using the following code:

```
for layer in model2.layers:
    layer.name = layer.name + str("_2")
```

After changing the names of the layers, **the second model gives a bad results**. 
When I remove the code of renaming, the second model gives a good accuracy.

How can I solve this problem?

Is there another way to change the layers names?

The complete code here:

```
model = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(64,64,3))
inp = model.input
out = model.output

model2 = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(64,64,3))

for layer in model2.layers:
    layer.name = layer.name + str("_2")

inp2 = model2.input
out2 = model2.output

merged = concatenate([out, out2])
merged = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(merged)

model_fusion = Model([inp, inp2], merged)
model_fusion.summary()
```